# Css, li full width of ul

Tags: css, list

I am trying to make an unordered list where the li elements span the full width of their parent ul.
For example, with your browser inspect the following code:

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

You will see that the li elements are not 100% of the line. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix that...

[image]

The yellow thing is the ul and the text starts like 50px to the right.

Comment: Each `<li>` takes up the full width for me. Do you have some CSS that might be affecting that?

Comment: No, that happens even to the code provided here. The text is not starting in the very beginning.

Comment: The `<ul>` has a default padding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list items (`<li>`) are taking up 100% of the space they're in. It's the default `padding` on the `<ul>` that you're seeing. Remove it with `ul {padding:0}`

```css
ul {padding:0}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ah, that's what the OP was talking about - the default padding. I assumed he had some override going on. Wish the OP posted his screenshot earlier!

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late screenshot!